# Pagination - displaytag

Tags: displaytag

I am using displaytag for pagination.  I want to know if there is a way to place another table inside a row.

Example, I want 3 columns - 1 Column its rowspan=3, 2nd column rowspan=3 and 3rd column has a table with 3 rows in that table.

```
<tr>
<td rowspan=3></td><td rowspan=3></td><td>
                                         <table>
                                               <tr>
                                                  <td></td>
                                                  <td></td>
                                                  <td></td>
                                               </tr>
                                         </table>
                                         </td>   
</tr>
```

I'm trying to see if I can do that with the displaytag decorator.  Can someone direct me to some documentation or an example? So I can change the structure of the table.  I see you can decorate the text but can you modify the actual table and still do the pagination?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to do rowspan with dispplaytag, but you can do this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td ></td><td ></td><td>
          <display:table name="test">
          </display:table>
      </td>   
   </tr>
</table>
```

If it's not good for your intent you can create an object with 3 of the objects of the collection.
In this way you can use a nested displaytag:
The first to implement the rowspan, and for the 3° column you can use another displaytag.